# Combining percentages differences

Tags: average, percentages

I would like to know the difference between two approaches of combining percentages.

I found an online example that match my situation; the example have been found in The University of Georgia page. It states:

"The data on 4 examinations showed scores of 75 percent correct, 87 percent correct, 69 percent correct, and 93 percent correct. The overall grade was determined by taking the Arithmetic Mean (or 'average') of these scores, reporting a combined percentage of 81.

```
75 + 87 + 69 + 93 / 4 = 81
```

Consider that the 4 examinations had:

24 correct out 32 questions for 75 percent

87 correct out of 100 questions for 87 percent

38 correct out of 55 questions for 69 percent

and 93 correct out of 100 questions for 93 percent.

Thus if the questions are of equal merit across the examinations, there are 242 questions answered correctly out of 287 for a percentage of 84.3."

I have similar situation on my research, and there is a difference between the percentages. I would like to understand the difference between these two computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that the first average regards each test as having equal weight, while the second average regards each question as having equal weight.

If it really doesn't matter how many questions are on a test, then the first average is better.

If it really doesn't matter how the question pool is divided up into tests, then the second average is better.

Long story short, neither is more correct without additional context.

Comment: Note also, the "averaging over questions" approach assumes that all questions are equally "hard" or "important", and similarly the "averaging over tests" assumes all tests are equally "hard" or equally "important". One can argue for variant schemes, e.g. if multiple people are taking the tests you can reassign the grading of each question or test to reflect the average over multiple test-takers, i.e. if only one person gets a question right then it's worth a lot for that person, but if everybody gets it right (or everybody gets it wrong) then it either counts very little or not at all.

Comment: I think your first sentence is saying exactly what my answer says ("weight" = "importance" = "hardness" = whatever). We both seem to be saying that there are many different weighting schemes, no one of which is more natural than the others.

Comment: yeah exactly, I was just expanding on your answer and saying "equal weight for tests" or "equal weight for questions" only scratches the surface of what you could do to get some kind of "objective" overall score for each test-taker based on the results on the questions and tests. For example, when I was grading tests for a calculus prof, he made me simply convert the students' rankings on each test's scores for a test into z-scores for the students on each test and then average the z-scores for a student and rank the averages to get the final grade (also converted to a bell curve).